oil furnace damper diameter: nominal or actual?
Are the diameter dimensions for an oil-furnace damper nominal or actual?  I need to replace ours since the little nut won't stay put any longer; the motion of the damper causes the nut to come loose and slide to a different spot.


I'm not sure about the answer to the size question, but there are things to do to keep a nut in place: a lock nut, thread locker liquid (if heat is a problem, there may be automotive thread locker).
